# json formatting, removing tags and new line

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following json output

> `{"text":[["blah blah blah"],["matt can get a car too"],["free audi r8
>   for mohammed"]]}`

from the following:

```
$sql = "select text from MO_test  order by id desc"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$json = array();
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
        $json['text'][]=$row; 
    }
}
mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($json);
```

what i want to achieve is the following:

1. tags to be removed, i.e. `""`, `[]` and `{}`, so that i am just left with what is in my database.
2. each new result to appear on a new line, so that my final output looks like this:

   `blah blah blah`
   `matt can get a car too`
   `free audi r8 for mohammed`

   Each one of these is an item in my database.

---

vardump

> array(1) { [0]=> string(14) "blah blah blah" } array(1) { [0]=>
>   string(22) "matt can get a car too" } array(1) { [0]=> string(25)
>   "free audi r8 for mohammed" } {"text":[["blah blah blah"],["matt can
>   get a car too"],["free audi r8 for mohammed"]]}

Comment: its not homework. its a problem i've got that i dont know how to solve hence the reason why i posted on here.

Comment: You will get down voted though becuase it appears you never even tried to do it yourself. Google.

Comment: if you dont like it, go do one. obviously i've tried looking and i couldn't find anything so i posted here.
(please excuse the rant)

Comment: Actually it's hard to distinguish people that did research and just don't mention it and those who just post without researching first. The default is to assume the second type since that seems to be true most of the time.

Comment: no problem. however that post wound me up abit. i do apologise if i was abit rude

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear what you want, but I think you should do

```
$sql = "select text from MO_test  order by id desc"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[0]."<br/>"; 
}

mysql_close($db_name);
```

Edit -To have everything in a json

```
$sql = "select text from MO_test  order by id desc"; //replace emp_info with your table name 
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$hmtl = '';

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $html .=  $row[0]."<br/>"; 
}

mysql_close($db_name);
echo json_encode($html);
```

Comment: here is the output of your code: Array
Array
Array
[]
it is what i want but with my data

Comment: @TuffyG can you just do var_dump($row); and post the output in your question?

Comment: @TuffyG ok, it's a plain array, so use `$row[0]` as in my edited answer and everything should be ok

Comment: that is the output i would like however it needs to be json for it to work in my app

Comment: @TuffyG if you need a json your code was ok!Thatwas a json!The extra [] and {} are just visual representations of data

Comment: yeah i realise i'm going to have to keep [] and {} however if i can seperate with new lines (even if i dont remove [] or {}) it would be good

Comment: i have tried your edit however it displays within the brower as one line however it doesnt show up in my app so i'm assuming it's not right..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need `[]` and `{}`, do not output in JSON format:

```
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { 
    echo $row[0] . "\n"; 
 }
```

Remove the `echo json_encode($json);` part, too.

Comment: Do you understand that [] and {} is must for JSON? tell what do you want to do? where you use that?

Comment: Read it in Android http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/ somethink like that.

Comment: maority of my code is similar to that however i needed to add     while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {builder.append(line + "\n"); but i still get the same issue. if removing the tags can't be done then it's ok as long as i can seperate each one with a new line

Comment: I think you are reading it like a simple string, not parsing into json object... If you need only read by newlines then i have edited my answer